# How can I support AutoField(primary_key=False) in django?

Tags: django, autofield

I need to add an autoinc field that is *not* the primary key. I am in the process of migrating a very large production database that uses autoincrementing fields to `models.UUIDField`. I have been doing a piecewise migration, and all of my relationships are now duplicated with both field types. I'm ready to make the primary key swap, but unfortunately I still need to keep the auto incrementing integer field for old clients as it becomes deprecated.

Since django will not allow me to define an autofield with `primary_key=False` (even though this is fully supported at the db layer), i'm looking for a simple solution. My initial strategy would be to simply change the field to `models.BigIntegerField('GUID', db_index=True, null=True, unique=True)` and then manually set the default `nextval('my_guid_seq'::regclass)` using `migrations.RunSQL`.  So far so good, except not. It turns out, because of my `null=True` declaration, django at the ORM layer is taking over and inserting `null` which will not allow defaults at the database layer to do it's job.

The core developers are fast to reject this request because of bad design, which I most definetly agree with, but there are very valid use cases such as this. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8576

I am a very weak django developer so I don't want to get in the weeds metaprogramming at the ORM layer. This is by definition a hack, so i'm looking for the least complex, creative solution that gets me around this limitation

Comment: It looks from 'my_guid_seq'::regclass that you are using postgresql, you can use postgreql sequences by editing the migration. But if you update your question and mention your real objective, you migt get a better answer.

Comment: @e4c5 i was a little afraid to tag postgres, because that part is working perfectly fine and I didn't want to distract the postgres community. Unfortunately my problem lies all the way up the stack with django's ORM.

Comment: Right so if you could explain the objective of this excercise we might find a way

Comment: My objective is to demote my autoinc primary keys and to use my UUID fields as primary keys. I am not removing the autoinc fields, just demoting them. Yes, all fks are updated, and yes all relationships are being maintained by UUIDs and autoincs

Comment: My objective is in the very first sentence.  Are you asking me *why* i'm switching from sequenced big integers to UUIDs?

Answer (score 6):

You could subclass `AutoField` and override the `_check_primary_key()` and the `deconstruct()` methods.

```py
from django.db.models.fields import AutoField
from django.db.models.fields import checks


class AutoFieldNonPrimary(AutoField):

    def _check_primary_key(self):
        if self.primary_key:
            return [
                checks.Error(
                    "AutoFieldNonPrimary must not set primary_key=True.",
                    obj=self,
                    id="fields.E100",
                )
            ]
        else:
            return []

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        kwargs["primary_key"] = False
        return name, path, args, kwargs
```

See `AutoField` source code [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L2352).

Comment: That error check is there for a reason, and bypassing it is likely to cause problems. I am not familiar enough with the internals of the Django ORM to predict what the consequences might be, but I would look for another workaround.

Comment: Without an example of what a consequence might be, I don't think that's enough to discredit his answer.  There is nothing stopping AUTO INCREMENT functionality being non-primary keyed at the database layer, so I couldn't foresee an issue.

Comment: After overriding, the errors stops for makemigrations, but when you actually try to migrate, we will get a error. When you output using sqlmigrate, you can see even the AutoFieldNonPrimary column would be marked as a PRIMARY, hence creating two primary keys are not allowed at the database level!

Comment: That happened to me once, but I just did a hacky solution of tweaking the query. Terrible fix but it had to be done.

Comment: Unexpected consequence: migrations does not work anymore on a model with that field. Considering an `AddField` operation with `field=AutoFieldNonPrimary(primary_key=False)`, you will get a  `multiple primary keys for table 'foo' are not allowed`. Seems @evergreen concerns were legitimate.

Comment: @user3785966 @David Dahan You'll also need to override the `deconstruct` method, which will be used to generate the migration https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-model-fields/#field-deconstruction

Answer (score 3):

I know, changing the primary key to UUID is such a pain.Hence the simple and better solution that I think of is to add another integer field that is auto-incrementing in nature.

Here is my solution:

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
    auto_inc_id = models.IntegerField()
```

Then override the save model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object_list = ModelName.objects.order_by('auto_inc_id')
    if len(self.object_list) == 0:  # if there are no objects
        self.auto_inc_id = 1
    else:
        self.auto_inc_id = self.object_list.last().auto_inc_id + 1
    super(ModelName, self).save()
```

Comment: I think `auto_inc_id + 1` can lead to a race condition if too many calls to save().

Comment: you mean override the save *function*? you could have shown it properly how overriding a model works, instead of posting the inner parts

Answer (score -2):

Couldn't format this as a comment, but modifying @Abhimanyu's answer to make the save method more concise (and issue only one query). Same model property:

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
    auto_inc_id = models.IntegerField()
```

And here's the save method on the model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.auto_inc_id = ModelName.objects.all().count() + 1
    super(ModelName, self).save()
```

Comment: Bad practice that could make your auto_inc_id nonsequential. Would advise against it.